# Google Apps Script Page is not opening

Tags: google-apps-script

I dare not to ask but I am using a google account of a friend in order to help him developing something with Apps Script. In Google Drive I open the Google Sheet. There I go to Extensions/Apps then normally the App Script editor appears which it does in my case. However in the case of the account I am using I get an error message that the page could not be found. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know why this is happening. However I found a workaround by typing script.google.com into the browser in order to reach it directly.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you have signed in into multiple Google accounts. Try one of the following:

1. Sign out of all accounts, then sign-in on only one account
2. Create a new web-browser profile
3. Use your web-browser in guest / private / incognito mode
4. Use a different web-browser

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and got the solution. Try editing some codes and saving them. If no edit is required, add some space somewhere and save. Then,  run the web app.
I opened the web app in dev mode. I don't know why this works every time. Maybe after editing, the Google script system assigns dev authority to the last edited user.